# Problema en compilación de Ionic 3 para Android ionic cordova platform add android@7.0.0

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

Buenas noches alguien podria ayudarme?? A que se debe este error cuando compilo y abro con Android  Studio me muestra este mensaje.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya intente con

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
ionic cordova platform add android@7.0.0
ionic cordova build android
```

Pero persiste el problema en la versión android@7.0.0

Es muy extraño ya que si me funciona cambiando a una versión anterior .

Usando:

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
ionic cordova platform add android@6.3.0
ionic cordova build android
```

Pero dando como resultado un mensaje como este:

***"To take advantage of all the latest features (such as Instant Run), improvements and security fixes, we strongly recommend that you update the Android Gradle plugin to version 3.0.1 and Gradle to version 4.1."***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Era un bug en el plugin, que no era compatible con cordova-android 7 porque cambió la estructura de la app.

Si instalas la versión 7.0.2 del plugin ya te debería funcionar